# Statistics - Standard Deviation of test statistic # of heads - # of tails

Tags: r, statistics, coin-flipping

I have a question concerning the following
N is the no. of coin tosses
H is the no. of heads obtained
T is the no. of tails obtained
Q = H-T

```
N = 100
H = 63
T = 37
Q = 26
```

Is this significant evidence that the coin is unbiased?
what is the standard deviation for q?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is better for cross validated https://stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

For n trials of a coin with probability p of Heads and, the difference Y=(H-T) is a random variable with mean = n (2 p - 1) and variance = 4 n p (1-p).
The following numerical simulation can be useful for a better understanding of the problem.

```
n <- 100
reps <- 100000
p <- 0.5

set.seed(4321)
y <- matrix(0,reps)
for (k in 1:reps) { 
 x <- rbinom(n, 1, p)
 Heads <- sum(x)
 Tails <- n - Heads
 y[k] <- Heads-Tails
}

mean(y)
[1] 0.01198
n*(2*p-1)
[1] 0

var(y)
         [,1]
[1,] 100.2223
4*n*p*(1-p)
[1] 100

hist(y, breaks=50, main="", freq=F)
curve(dnorm(x,mean=n*(2*p-1),sd=sqrt(4*n*p*(1-p))),-40,40, 
      add=T, lwd=2, col="red")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are assuming the coin **is biased** to start with, you would need a prob(head) value to then test the coin was unbiased.

Given the data you supplied, you could do a binomial test to see if the coin **was** biased.

```
n <- 100
h <- 63
p <- 0.5

binom.test(h, n, p, alternative = "greater")

    Exact binomial test

data:  h and n
number of successes = 63, number of trials = 100,
p-value = 0.006016
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is greater than 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.5434341 1.0000000
sample estimates:
probability of success 
                  0.63
```

This the p-value is 0.6%, which would suggest we reject the null hypothesis in favour of the alternative. i.e. We think the coin is biased.

The 95% confidence interval of [0.54, 1] is further evidence the coin is biased as it suggests P(H) > 0.5